# Retrieving unique values from a large PyArrow Dataset

Tags: pyarrow

I have a large dataset (definitely larger than memory) stored in a number of Hive-partitioned parquet files. I'm currently using PyArrow's `dataset` to conveniently handle the files as a single logical dataset - which I believe is the intent behind the existence of PyArrow's dataset :-)

Now I'd need to extract all of the *distinct* values of a column of that dataset - or even better, distinct tuples of values of a set of columns of that dataset, say columns "first_name" and "last_name". The set of distinct values is itself small enough to fit in memory.

Is there a way to extract these distinct values directly from the dataset, without materializing the dataset into a Table first - which wouldn't fit in memory?

P.S.: of course I can use `to_batches`, convert each batch to a Table, get the distinct items from the table, and aggregate them up into a global aggregate...but I was hoping for a built-in solution :-)

Answer (score 3):

The [acero engine](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/acero.html) can do this.

```py
import pyarrow.acero as ac

ac.Declaration.from_sequence([
    ac.Declaration('scan', ac.ScanNodeOptions(dataset)),
    ac.Declaration('aggregate', ac.AggregateNodeOptions([], ['first_name', 'last_name'])),
]).to_table()
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about `acero`.